# Most efficient way to access specific key of a map with an iterator?

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, key

I have a `std::map<std::string,int>` from which I'd like to access a specific element with an iterator from a string value. I wrote the following code which does it.

```
map<string,int> mymap;
map<string,int>::iterator it=mymap.begin();

string find="Node";
        while( (it->first) !=find && it!= mymap.end())
               it++;
```

Is looping through the whole key elements of the map the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Taking a look at [some documentation for `std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) might reveal a few clues...

Comment: Or http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

Comment: Thanks for the information on the subject, I didn't know of that member function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
map<string,int>::iterator it = mymap.find("Node");
```

[That's all.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find)

Comment: Thanks for the syntax of how to implement it on the example code I provided, I'll make this the answer since it follows up the example and can be used in the future as a reference.

Answer (score 2):

map is just a binary search tree. A given key can be found in `O(log(N))` time. Iterating through the whole list will take `O(N)` time.

If you want an iterator, use the `find` method of map. If you want a reference to the data, just use `operator[]`. Both of these will run in `O(log(N))` time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find an element on a map, use the [find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/) member method.
A map is an associated container optimized for this type of operation, no need to loop over the keys.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the "find" function of map?